# html. Show ip address at browser address bar instead of actual website address

Tags: php, html, server

I'm working on a project where at a place I want to change my normal website address to ip address ie address http:/www.mydomain.com/index.php will change into http:/192.xx.xxx.25/. This will be only for one specific page not for whole site.
Can anyone help me how i will be able to do this. Thanks....

Comment: What? Can you please clarify what you want to do?

Comment: One specific page? It's going to be a bit more complicated than you think. I'm concerned for your intentions here...

Comment: I just want to change my normal website address ie http:/www.mydomain.com to some ip address like http:/192.268.xx.xxx.

Comment: A bit more in elaboration, when some one try to open http:/www.mydomain.com/index.php, it will be redirected in such a way that browser address bar will show some ip address http:/xxx.xx.xxx.xx/ instead of e.g. http:/www.mydomain.com/index.php.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache you can do it using htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 /specific_page_slug http://192.168.0.1
```

For Nginx you can add following in your Nginx configuration file

```
location Old {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ File redirect;
}

location /specific_page_slug {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.1 redirect;
}

location / {
  if ($http_host ~ "^example.com"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 redirect;
  }
}
```

Comment: What? This is not an answer! We don't even know what the OP is hosting on! Flagged.

Comment: If I understand well OP wants to redirect an page to specific IP address.

Comment: Using what? On what platform?

Comment: `htaccess` is related to Apache. How is that not abstracting too far?